# How to extract substring from string in crystal report

Tags: database, string, crystal-reports, substring

I am new to crystal reports.

My data(employee ids) is of the following format

```
Abc123, uttd333, ddt-435
```

I want to extract only numbers and remove leading letters and special characters.

Also there are certain values that should never be printed.

Admin Ids such as

Gree999, ttt999

I know there is a mid function but that requires me to specify the position from where the substring should begin. These values don't have a fixed number of leading letters.

Is there anything like Ltrim like we have in SQL that we can use to achieve this in crystal reports?

Comment: Would it be possible to handle the string manipulation within your database using either parameterized SQL scripts or stored procedures?  This would allow you to make use of regular expression evaluations that you can't use in Crystal Reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik there's no built-in function in CR to remove non-numeric characters from a string, so you'll have to roll your own (replace {Befehl.EmployeeId} with your field):

```
StringVar employeeId := {Befehl.EmployeeId};
StringVar result := "";
NumberVar i;

// transfer numeric chars into result one by one
For i := 1 To Length(employeeId) Do
(
  If IsNumeric(employeeId[i]) Then
     result := result + employeeId[i];
);

// output result only if employeeId is not in your admin list
If employeeId In Split('Gree999,ttt999', ',') Then
  '--Admin--'
Else
  result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative approach to grabbing just the numeric portion of the string:
strReverse(ToText(Val(strReverse({EmpId})),0,""))

It takes advantage of knowing that the digits are always at the end.

Comment: Hi, this approach leaves the training zeroes. For example, one of my id was printed as 123 but in reality it was 12300 so , it should have printed as 12300

Answer (score 0):

To handle trailing zeros, you can use:

```
local stringvar withoutTrailingZeros := strReverse(ToText(Val(strReverse({EmpId})),0,""));
withoutTrailingZeros + ReplicateString("0", Len({EmpId}) - (instr({EmpId}, withoutTrailingZeros) + Len(withoutTrailingZeros) - 1))
```

But mweber's answer above is simpler now.